# zuul filter doesn't intercept /login endpoint

Tags: java, spring, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-oauth2

in my zuul i use spring oauth. `/login` endpoint is handled automatically by spring. i wan't to add post filter to change some redirection responses (302) returned by this endpoint

but it seems like my post filter is never called on the url. why? how can i enable the filter for this endpoint?

```
@Component
public class MyFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "post";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        // this is not called for /login endpoint
    }
}
```

my route config:

```yaml
zuul:
  ignoredPatterns: /**/management/**,/folder/**,/search/**,/assets/**
  add-host-header: true
  add-proxy-headers: true
  routes:
    sites:
      path: /api/site/**
      serviceId: sites
    drive:
      path: /api/drive/**
      serviceId: drive
    search:
      path: /api/search/**
      serviceId: search
    chassis:
      path: /api/page/**
      serviceId: chassis
    uaa:
      path: /uaa/**
      url: http://localhost:8080/uaa/
      sensitiveHeaders:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 5000
    socket-timeout-millis: 10000
  ribbon-isolation-strategy: thread


proxy:
  auth:
    routes:
      drive: oauth2
      sites: oauth2
```

but i also have `@EnableOAuth2Sso` there

Comment: Can you post your route configuration?

Comment: @NickDeFazio route config posted